# amCharts 4 - Second Y Axis doesn't show values

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I am setting up a new chart using amCharts 4 js library. I need to show the y Axis both on the left side and on the right side.

I followed the documentation and set "opposite = true" for the second y Axis (to have it on the right). This Axis seems to be rendered but without the values which are on the left side.

If I use only one y Axis and set "opposite = true", it works perfectly. But when I set it up for the second y Axis, the chart does not show the values of the right Axis but only on the left one.

```
// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
var valueAxisLeft = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
var valueAxisRight = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxisRight.renderer.opposite = true;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zs2gnd41/

In this jsfiddle example, the chart has the "empty" space for the right Y Axis but it doesn't show it. If you comment out the latest 2 lines of this above snippet, the chart will become wider.

Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle with the chart code? It would make debugging much easier.

Comment: @fabio.sang just did it! thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

You can create one more series for right axis [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01s943hw/1/),

```
var valSeriesRight = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
valSeriesRight.dataFields.valueY = "value";
valSeriesRight.dataFields.dateX = "date";
valSeriesRight.yAxis = valueAxisRight;
```

Comment: can we change the right side values to percent values?